# Error uploading file in nestjs : Argument type Type<NestInterceptor> is not assignable to parameter type NestInterceptor | Function

Tags: nestjs

My Code :
[image]

FileInterceptor error code : Argument type Type is not assignable to parameter type NestInterceptor | Function

more info :
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';

Can you tell me why the red line shows the error? Help me!

Answer (score 0):

... Shutting down IDE and restarting, the error disappeared